# Android Force Recycle Large Bitmap?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

From another stackoverflow question, it seems that Android handles large bitmaps differently than other memory. It also seems like there is a way to force Android to recycle the bitmaps to free up memory. Can anyone enlighten me on how to do this.

My application uses 2-6 huge bitmaps at all times, so it nearly kills the phone's memory when running, and I want to clear it up when the user quits.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lol. Just found the bitmap.recycle() method. Never mind.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure if anybody is not using the Bitmap before call the method recycle(). If anybody is using the Bitmap and you try recycle, one exception is call.

Answer (score 0):

Check answer in this post [how to compress image for imageview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125779/how-to-compress-image-for-imageview-in-android)
you can extract thumbnails of your images and use them as bitmap.
After calling bitmap.recycle() you can use System.gc(); to call the garbage collector